# Como ingresar caracteres especiales en un TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, visual-studio-2022

Para mi trabajo de título estoy haciendo un sistema de gestión de productos y ventas para un negocio. Estoy utilizando c# con .net y SQL Server como motor de base de datos.

Mi problema es: cuando quiero agregar un producto a mi base de datos, el asunto es que si quiero ingresar el nombre de un producto con caracteres especiales (Ñ-ñ) como también ingresar el acento (´) pero me sale el mensaje de alerta que solo puedo ingresar letras y números. Les dejo el código que utilizo en el evento KeyPress que asigné al TextBox:

```
private void txtNombreAgregarProducto_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if
        ((e.KeyChar >= 33 && e.KeyChar <= 43) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 45 && e.KeyChar <= 47) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 91 && e.KeyChar <= 96) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 123 && e.KeyChar <= 129) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 131 && e.KeyChar <= 143) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 145 && e.KeyChar <= 159) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 166 && e.KeyChar <= 180) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 182 && e.KeyChar <= 223) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 225 && e.KeyChar <= 232) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 234 && e.KeyChar <= 238) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 240 && e.KeyChar <= 255))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sólo puede ingresar Letras, espacio y números", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }   
}
```

el tema es que con esas validaciones me permitiría ingresar los caracteres mencionados y hasta letras con acento, pero al ejecutar y tratar de ingresar, me lanza el Mensaje que asigné.

Según tabla ASCII, el acento agudo es 239, los caracteres Ñ y ñ son respectivamente 164 y 165, pero también me lanza mensaje.

Que puedo hacer? hasta vi el idioma de mi teclado por si era eso.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: La codificación ASCII comprende los código del 0 al 127. Es decir, 7 bits. De 128 a 255 estás hablando de ASCII extendido o Unicode, que son codificaciones diferentes. Deberías cambiar la codificación de la base de datos o algo del estilo. No sé cómo se hace.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentas Ñ y ñ son respectivamente 164 y 165 en ASCII, y el carácter del acento no tiene valor [image: Jorgesys csharp ascii],

me parece que la mejor opción en estos casos es usar una REGEX:

```
private void txtNombreAgregarProducto_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    /*if
        ((e.KeyChar >= 33 && e.KeyChar <= 43) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 45 && e.KeyChar <= 47) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 91 && e.KeyChar <= 96) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 123 && e.KeyChar <= 129) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 131 && e.KeyChar <= 143) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 145 && e.KeyChar <= 159) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 166 && e.KeyChar <= 180) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 182 && e.KeyChar <= 223) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 225 && e.KeyChar <= 232) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 234 && e.KeyChar <= 238) ||
         (e.KeyChar >= 240 && e.KeyChar <= 255))
        {*/

        string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜñÑ'´\s]+$";
    
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), pattern))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sólo puede ingresar Letras, espacio y números", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }   

}
```

de esta forma podrías validar usar letras, números, acentos y ñ Ñ.

Puedes probar la REGEX que sugiero [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/bZQIYG/1)

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias. Ahora otra duda si quiero borrar la letra Ñ o una palabra entera sin que el teclado me de el mensaje al presionar la tecla que está sobre el enter para borrar? y si quiero ingresar un numero mayor a zero es cosa de modificar el regex, no?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Si, se puede modificar el REGEX, dime especificamente que deseas y te ayudo

Comment: ya lo modifiqué para solo letras, solo que gracias al regex no puedo borrar la letra o la palabram por lo que me da el mensaje de solo letras y numeros. Y como modificar el regex para agregar puntos, guion entre otros. Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mira lo más fácil para validar carcteres alfanumericos es usar `char.IsLetterOrDigit`

Ejemplo

```
private void txtNombreAgregarProducto_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(!char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sólo puede ingresar Letras, espacio y números", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

---

Por otro lado digamos que sigues el camino de comparar por carácter, para esto no es necesario emplear el número de la tabla ASCII, C# te permite comparar por un rango de char.

```
private void txtNombreAgregarProducto_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (isAceptable(e.KeyChar))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SI ES VALIDO");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NO ES VALIDO");
    }
}

private bool isAceptable(char c) => c switch
{
    >= '0' and <= '9' => true,
    >= 'A' and <= 'Z' => true,
    >= 'a' and <= 'z' => true,
    'á' or 'Á' => true,
    'é' or 'É' => true,
    'í' or 'Í' => true,
    'ó' or 'Ó' => true,
    'ú' or 'Ú' => true,
    'ñ' or 'Ñ' => true,
    _ => false
};
```

Comment: Es lo que iba a recomendar, pero no he podido probar esta función con caracteres internacionales, según esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975640/check-if-char-isletter-without-special-characters-like-%C3%A1 sí incluye los caracteres internacionales